# Keeping track of state up and down recursion tree w/ React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

I'm recursively displaying a questionnaire (each question is a component).  To advance from one question to the next, the current question must be answered (receive user input), as the answer determines the next question to appear.

Currently my code

- displays the first question
- gets user input
- recurses and displays the appropriate second question
- I can answer this and continue in that pattern

The issue is that I would like to edit the answer to a question and have the next questions be updated according to this new answer, but I am unable to edit answers (except for the first question).

I think this is because I have exited recursion, so the only editable answer is the first one (which is bottom level so accessible outside recursion).  My initial thought was to incorporate a waiting period with await, to wait for user input before continuing with recursion/execution. I can only find examples for await javascript functions rather than components though, and am also cognizant this may not be the correct approach.  Does anybody have any pointers for how to either pause recursion/execution until the user has answered the question OR how to jump back into a specific loop of recursion?  Questions, once displayed, should all be able to be edited (ie I should be able to answer 4 questions and then edit question 2, which would then update question 3 and remove question 4)

Actual code is shown in code sandbox below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-frost-wzwxh?file=/src/App.js

THANK YOU!

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  const onChange = answers => this.setState({ answers })
  return (
    <RecursiveComponent
      questions={questions} // hardcoded JSON object (for now)
      onChange={onChange}
      answers={this.state.answers}
    />
  )
}
```

Display func (displays + updates answers object in local recurse loop + in parent comp when answer provided)

```
const DisplayComponent = ({answers, question, onChange}) => {
  handleChange = (id, answers) => {
    ...my update logic
    onChange(answers) // updates answers parent component
  }
  return <ComponentToDisplay/>
```

}

Recursive component that recurses through nested question list (logic removed)

```
const RecursiveComponent = ({questions, answers, onChange}) => {
  return (
    // map through questions 
    //for each question
    <DisplayComponent 
      answers={answers} 
      question={curr_question} 
      onChange={onChange}/>
  
    // if current question has been answered and
    // there are nested questions 
    <RecursiveComponent 
      questions={nested questions} 
      // curr answer and curr children's nested answers
      answers={answers[questionID]} 
      onChange={answer => (answers = {answer})}
}
```

Comment: Not yet [React Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html).  Please also include your code here and not on an external site.  See [mre].

Comment: Added code.  Thank you @zero298

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `await` to wait, you can set a `false` state variable, and use a `setTimeout` to change the state to `true` after a few seconds, and then have the later questions optionally render depending on that state variable.

Also in your code, the reason that it is exiting is because you are only defining one nesting of `{/* check each branch for matching answer */}`, you are not actually recursing fully down the tree.

Comment: How would the timeout help, knowing I would only ever want to display the next question if the current question has been answered?  I'm also confused how the variable with the timeout would help me pause execution as opposed to simply skipping things (ie not executing something if the variable resolves false).